# How can I remove the arrow from drop down list in Bootstrap CSS?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to remove the arrow that appears on a drop down menu in Twitter Bootstrap framework. Has anyone figured a way of removing the arrows?

Comment: I removed <b class="caret"></b> and the arrow is gone,that solved it.

Comment: If you found your answer before it was posted, post it as an answer below and approve it to close this thread, that way it can help future users as well.

Comment: @Andres,the think with memebers with less than 100 reps. they cant answer their own question before 8 hours are over.I have accepted an answer,thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From: https://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#buttonDropdowns

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
    Action
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <!-- dropdown menu links -->
  </ul>
</div>
```

If you remove `<span class="caret"></span>` the arrow is not shown.

Tried it using the dev. console in Chrome, and seems to work.

Comment: @TahirAlvi Done. In the future, feel free to update links without notifying the author.

Answer (score 26):

Removing the caret class from the link removes the arrow from the navigation bar,

```
.dropdown-menu::before, 
.dropdown-menu::after {
    border: none;
    content: none;
}
```

Will remove the little tab from the drop down menu its self.

Comment: I was force to add the `!important` flag to override the bootstrap settings.  There's quite a few layers of specificity on the original declaration.

Comment: You are not forced to add `!important`. Just make your rules more specific than the bootstrap ones.

Answer (score 4):

If you copy an existing Bootstrap dropdown example, the menu button tag looks something like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu Name</button>
```

Removing the `dropdown-toggle` class removes the arrow (or caret):

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu Name</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
.dropdown-toggle::after{
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just remove border-bottom from dropdown-menu will remove arrow from the navigation bar.

```
.navbar .nav > li > .dropdown-menu:before, .navbar .nav > li > .dropdown-menu:after{
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found the best solution is to add `overflow:hidden;` to `.dropdown-menu`

Comment: I used this solution to prevent the caret from showing up in a side menu when the menu was collapsed against the side of the screen. +1 for a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use dropdown-bs-toggle instead of dropdown-toggle

Answer (score -1):

add `.dropdown-toggle-split` class in the  tag

Answer (score -1):

The only thing that worked for me was that I removed `class="caret"` if you are using bootstrap dropdown. Hope this work for you too.

Answer (score -1):

In Bootstrap4 remove "dropdown-toggle" class from "a" element.