# How to remove the arrow in dropdown in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4. I tried to remove the arrow in dropdown.

The [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10244773/how-can-i-remove-the-arrow-from-drop-down-list-in-bootstrap-css) I found for Bootstrap 3 do not work any more.

The jsfiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Hongbo_Miao/ujLnh9y7/1/).

```
<div class="dropdown open">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 306, accepted):

Simply remove "`dropdown-toggle`" class from the element. The dropdown will still work if you have the `data-toggle` attribute as follows

```
<button role="button" type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="dropdown"> 
    Dropdown Without Arrow
</button>
```

overriding `.dropdown-toggle` class styles affects all dropdowns and you may want to keep the arrow in other buttons, that's why this looks to me the simplest solution.

**Edit**: Keep `dropdown` class if you want to keep border styling

```
<button role="button" type="button" class="btn dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown"> 
    Dropdown Without Arrow
</button>
```

Comment: For some reason, the other solutions weren't working for me. I'm running Bootstrap 4. This was the only thing that worked.

Comment: This didn't quite work for me. The right side of the button is no longer rounded.

Comment: Simpler than writing custom CSS with `!important` :)

Comment: I tested this and it works pretty well! Tested in FF, Chrome, IE and Opera - even on mobile android devices with build-in browser no annoying arrow - thanks alot sir! NOTICE: don't remove the complete "dropdown-toggle" attribute, just remove the "-toggle" attribute, so your styling for the dropdownmenu don't get rid. So "dropdown-toggle" turns to "dropdown" - hope this helps.

Comment: This one is working for v5 very nicely. Thanks.

Answer (score 149):

With css, you could just do that:

```
.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: I also had to include `!important` to get this custom CSS to take effect.

Comment: This will impact every dropdown used in other pages if you are using the same CSS.

Comment: add some more prefix to only disable arrow for button, eg:


.btn.btn-outline-secondary.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display:none !important;
}

Answer (score 80):

I don't recommend any of the existing answers because:

- `.dropdown-toggle` has more styling than just the caret. Removing the class from the element causes [styling issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38576503/how-to-remove-the-arrow-in-dropdown-in-bootstrap-4#comment83418845_44577512).
- Overriding `.dropdown-toggle` doesn't make sense. Just because you don't need a caret on some particular element, doesn't mean you won't need one later.
- `::after` doesn't cover [dropdown variants](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#dropleft-variation) (some use `::before`).

Use a custom `.caret-off` in the same element as your `.dropdown-toggle` element:

```
.caret-off::before {
    display: none;
}
.caret-off::after {
    display: none;
}
```

Some have said they needed to add `!important` but YMMV.

Comment: Best answer, I'd just add some extra info for other people, like this class should be added along with `dropdown-toggle`.

Comment: this is a very helpful answer - tried the `no-arrow` option, didn't help.

Comment: Great answer. In my case, I needed to add `!important`. Eg: `display: none !important;`.

Comment: This is the best answer compared to the others.

Comment: @TranAnhMinh maybe that's because you're including your custom CSS before Bootstrap?

Comment: !important needed for bootstrap 4.6

Comment: !important is bad practice... CSS is supposed to treat the last entry as the winner (as the one to be applied) to our website. I tried above method with Bootstrap 4 and Bootstrap 5 and it works fine.

Comment: For anyone that needs an override, this is the right approach.

Answer (score 27):

remove the `dropdown-toggle` class

Comment: That's more like a comment

Comment: That is what [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44577512/1364007) said six months before this one: "*Simply remove "dropdown-toggle" class from the element.*"

Answer (score 9):

```
.dropdown-toggle::after { 
 content: none; 
 }
```

You can also try this

Comment: This was so helpful. It solved my whole issue! Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

If you are interested in replacing the arrow with another Icon (such as, FontAwesome) you would just need to remove the border on the pseudo element of .dropdown-toggle

```
.dropdown-toggle::after { border: none; }
```

Answer (score 5):

I was using the accepted answer for quite a while in my project but just now stumbled across a [variable used by bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss):

```
$enable-caret: true !default;
```

If you set this to false then the caret will be removed without having to do any custom code.

My project was Ruby/Rails so I was using the [bootstrap-rubygem](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-rubygem). I changed the variable by importing a `custom-variables.scss` with the above variable set to false in my `application.scss` **BEFORE** the `bootstrap.scss` file/files.

Answer (score 4):

If you remove fit the dropdown-toggle class as below, all the dropdown buttons on your system will no longer have the caret.

```
.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display:none;
}
```

But maybe that's not what you want, so to remove just the specific button, we're going to insert a class called: remoecaret, and we'll fit the class: dropdown-toggle as follows:

```
.removecaret.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display: none;
}
```

and our html looks something like:

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm dropdown-toggle removecaret" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
    <li><a href="#"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Edit</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Boostrap generates this using the CSS border:

```
.dropdown-toggle:after {
  border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna exactly only in this bootstrap button class, make:

```
.btn .dropdown-toggle::after {
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried tag="a" within the class? it hides the arrow without further css.

Answer (score -1):

Add no-arrow to drop-down toggle class declaration

Answer (score -2):

This works on bootsrap4 and ng-bootstrap.

```
.dropdown-toggle:after {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Copying the two year old accepted answer, but with a typo.