# How can I create a ng-boostrap dropdown without any arrow?

Tags: ng-bootstrap

The [ng-bootstrap dropdown](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown) has a text as well as a drop down arrow icon next to the text.

[image]

How can I convert this dropdown to something like below which does not have any text but have only three dots like ...

[image]

Comment: you will probably want to roll your own as you're going to have to change the 3rd party code, which you don't really want to do... depends what you trying to achieve, you're really just hiding and showing a ul... you could just use a popover with its own styles and a template for the html??

Comment: The answer is in the stackoverflow [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38576503/how-to-remove-the-arrow-in-dropdown-in-bootstrap-4).